# Resizing a raster to match specific dimensions in R

Tags: r, raster

I want to resize (enlarge in this case) a raster to match the dimensions of another.  Using `disaggregate` I can enlarge the raster, but the resize factor argument only accepts integers, so the output is closer to but not matching the target dimensions.  The following example illustrates by trying to resize `ras2` to match `ras1` dimensions:

```
> require(raster)
> ras1 = raster(volcano)
> ras2 = aggregate(raster(apply(volcano, 1, rev)), fact=2, FUN=mean) # aggregated & rotated
> extent(ras1) = extent(ras2) = c(0,100,0,100)
> crs(ras1) = crs(ras2) = '+init=epsg:27700'
> fact = c(ncol(ras1) / ncol(ras2), nrow(ras1) / nrow(ras2))
> ras2_resized = disaggregate(ras2, fact, method='')
> dim(ras2_resized)
[1] 93 44  1
> dim(ras1)
[1] 87 61  1
```

Grateful if anyone knows of a way to specify the dimensions of a resize instead of factor.  Thanks in advance.

Bonus for a generalised method that can resizing either way not just enlarging, but this isn't the priority.

Comment: This is not trivial, since enlarging by a nonintegral factor requires 2-D interpolation.  You can do it using `akima:interp` .

Comment: Cheers Carl. Please add as a solution and I'll tick.

Comment: Go ahead and select your answer --you did the heavy work :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resample function can also be used for this:

```
 ras2_resized <- resample(ras2, ras1)
```

Comment: Thanks that's spot on

Comment: This only works when both raster intersect. What if they do not intersect? Should be kept in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In line with Carl's suggestion the following works for me, although I'm sure there's a more elegant formulation:

```
> require(akima)
> pts1 = rasterToPoints(ras1)
> pts2 = rasterToPoints(ras2)
> intp = interp(x=pts2[,1], y=pts2[,2], z=pts2[,3], xo=unique(pts1[,1]), yo=unique(pts1[,2]))
> ras2_resized = flip(raster(apply(intp$z, 1, rev)),'y') # flipped and rotated
> dim(ras2_resized)
[1] 87 61  1
> dim(ras1)
[1] 87 61  1
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, tho' I suspect you can skip the `rasterToPoints` stuff so long as you're working with single-layer raster objects.